# Database is lost in Project - Not in Assets

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio

Normally to make changes in my Database I followed the following steps:

- Edited Database in SQLite
- Delete Database in my assets folder
- Copy paste Database in assets folder again
- Delete the App from my phone through settings
- Rebuild/install the app

This worked for me beforehand many times. No I have the issue that somehow my project does not access this database anymore.

**I figured that out by deleting the database from my asset folder and reinstalling the app. The App still works, therefore it does not access the database from my asset folder that I used beforehand, to the best of my knowledge.**

I am using the following path to access it:

```
DB_Path = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_Name).
Log.e("DB_path", DB_Path);
```

Which yields

`.com.example.chris.projectartifact E/DB_path:/data/user/0/com.example.chris.projectartifact/databases/myDB.db`.

**Regarding the Comment:**

I am using the following method to copy my Database.
This is from a tutorial and it worked fine for a very long time.
From my understanding though `FileOutputStream(DB_Path)`
copies it to named path.

```
public void copyDataBase(){
        try {
            InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_Name);
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_Path);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length=myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                myOutput.write(buffer,0,length);
            }
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("Error:","in CopyDatabase, where are in catch..");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**The Questions:**

- Where do I find my database in my structure?
- How am I able to update it?
- **New Question:** *How do i delete my copied database and renew it from my asset folder?*

Answer (score 0):

If your db is in your assets folder, its not on the file system at all-  its in your assets-  its part of the APK file (and thus read only).  If you need it to be read write, you need to copy it to the filesystem first, and then you can put it where you want (although in the database path is traditional it isn't enforced).

Comment: Thanks for your Input Gabe. I think i copied the database a long time ago. I updated my post with the copyDatabase method. Could you please elaborate how I am able to delete the copied database and renew it? (I updated my post accordingly)

Comment: Hey Gabe, I am still kind of confused by your answer. Would you mind to eloborate it more clearly please?

Comment: Hey Gabe. What I did now was the delete my Database with `context.deleteDatabase("myDB.db");` .. The issue is that I do not know how to copy the one from the asset folder into the filesystem as you explained. Can you please help me with that? **My CopyDataBase Method does not seem to work.**